# When concerned or where concerned

Tags: expressions

Which is correct?

He does that when his wife is concerned

He does that where his wife is concerned.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your question is unclear. Please provide more context and show _some_ research.

Comment: I have up-voted. This is a valid question that will be difficult to research. 'Where' in this kind of expression does not denote a location.

Comment: It depends on your meaning: ... (at times) when... or ... (in situations) where...

Comment: @NigelJ [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/where) covers it (B2).

Comment: 'Where' is used as a conjunction but its use may be conceptual, not physical. The situations referred to are not (necessarily) physical or material but abstract and logical. 'Where' his wife is concerned refers to something metaphysical. It is perfectly clear what is being asked and it is a valid linguistic aspect of the English Language.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct and in common usage, perhaps modified on transatlantic ships/aircraft. But I would suggest "where his wife is concerned" is more popular/common.
Where in this expression does not solely mean location as it can refer to a non-literal location or context. "When...concerned....has a similar meaning to "where...concerned", but may be used to include an idea of "instance" or a number of times the wife was concerned.